# Counting and appending sublist elements in python

Tags: python, sublist

I'm trying to count the number of unique instances of a sublist element, then write each unique element to a new list, with the number of instances appended to the sublist. Each sublist in list_1 will have only two elements and order does not matter.

so:

```
list_1 = [[a, b], [a, c], [a, c], [a, c], [b, e], [d, q], [d, q]]
```

becomes:

```
new_list =  [[a, b, 1], [a, c, 3], [b, e, 1], [d, q, 2]]
```

I'm thinking that i'll need to use sets, but I appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `[a, c, 3], [a, c, 1]`?

Comment: Also, are identical elements of `list_1` guaranteed to be consecutive?

Comment: Must these be `list()`s or would `tuple()`s do?

Comment: Small quibble: by definition, the number of instances of a *unique* element will be exactly 1. I think you mean that you want to count the number of occurrences of each pair in `list_1`?

Comment: removed [a, c, 1], a typo. yes, identical elements will be consecutive.

Comment: a tuple should do---thanks Joel I'm trying to count occurrences of each pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If identical sublists are consecutive:

```
from itertools import groupby

new_list = [sublist + [sum(1 for _ in g)] for sublist, g in groupby(list_1)]
# -> [['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'c', 3], ['b', 'e', 1], ['d', 'q', 2]]
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to look at [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); `Counter` objects are multi-sets (also known as bags); they map keys to their counts.

You *will* have to turn your sublists into tuples to be usable as keys though:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(tuple(e) for e in list_1)

new_list = [list(e) + [count] for e, count in counts.most_common()]
```

which gives you a `new_list` sorted by counts (descending):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_1 = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'e'], ['d', 'q'], ['d', 'q']]
>>> counts = Counter(tuple(e) for e in list_1)
>>> [list(e) + [count] for e, count in counts.most_common()]
[['a', 'c', 3], ['d', 'q', 2], ['a', 'b', 1], ['b', 'e', 1]]
```

If your occurrences are always consecutive, then you could also use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def counted_groups(it):
    for entry, group in groupby(it, key=lambda x: x):
        yield entry + [sum(1 for _ in group)]

new_list = [entry for entry in counted_groups(list_1)]
```

I used a separate generator function here, you can inline the loop into the list comprehension though.

This gives:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def counted_groups(it):
...     for entry, group in groupby(it, key=lambda x: x):
...         yield entry + [sum(1 for _ in group)]
... 
>>> [entry for entry in counted_groups(list_1)]
[['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'c', 3], ['b', 'e', 1], ['d', 'q', 2]]
```

and retains the original ordering.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of a 'round the houses' solution

```
list_1 = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'e'], ['d', 'q'], ['d', 'q']]
new_dict={}
new_list=[]
for l in list_1:
    if tuple(l) in new_dict:
        new_dict[tuple(l)] += 1
    else:
        new_dict[tuple(l)] = 1
for key in new_dict:
    entry = list(key)
    entry.append(new_dict[key])
    new_list.append(entry)
print new_list
```